# React Navigation v5 Set StatusBar barStyle for all screen

Tags: react-navigation

We can set `StatusBar` style individually per screen as per [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/status-bar)

But is there a way to set it for all screens?

The `StatusBar` is black on light theme, that looks fine. But because it's white on dark theme, it's hardly visible on my app. Would like to set it to black on all screens.

Comment: Hello, did you ever find an answer for this?